# Is it possible to make .tt-input wider?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

The `typeahead` example [on the typeahead website](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) seems to limit the width of the `.tt-input` using `3em !important` in the `style` of the element, so that when you type something which is longer than `3em` it starts to scroll out of view in this tiny input.

How can I make `.tt-input` wider?

Here is a screenshot to help explain what I'm talking about: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vvt9qc.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be hardcoded into bootstrap-tagsinput.js, see lines 46-47:

```
var inputWidth = (this.inputSize < 3 ? 3 : this.inputSize) + "em";
this.$input.get(0).style.cssText = "min-width: " + inputWidth + " !important;";
```

`inputSize` is computed based on the placeholder text. If there is none, it will default to `3em`. You might want to change these lines to obtain a different value, or remove the attribute altogether. I'm not entirely sure why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

set the class to this:

```
input.tt-input {
width:auto !important;
}
```

... make sure you put it AFTER the typehead css so that it's overwritten.

Comment: The '3em !important' is added to the style of the element, so it doesn't matter if you change it in the css, the element style will overwrite it with '3em !important' again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Eepzy is correct: `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` does use the `placeholder` text to determine the size of the input field, but the `3em` is only used if you don't have a `placeholder` text that is a least 3 characters long.

I think editing a 3rd party js is not good practice in general.

There is a different solution to our problem: just use a placeholder text.

```
<input type="text" class="tagsinput" placeholder="Type here..."/>
```

Any text (except whitespaces) will do as long as it is at least 3 characters long.